# SVG image Download URL Link is not working in FFImageLoading in Xamarin Forms

Tags: svg, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I have stored the image in google drive and set the link url to FFImageLoading source. The svg image is not showing. Please refer the [SVG image URL Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N87mK4CZvjmJc4HkKSiBTFhSpKRtUan4/view). I have tried many suggestion from stackoverflow, but that all are not working to me. I have used the below code to show the SVG image,

```
<ffSvg:SvgCachedImage
   Margin="0"
   HeightRequest="50"
   RetryCount="3"                                
   Source="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N87mK4CZvjmJc4HkKSiBTFhSpKRtUan4/view"
   WidthRequest="50" />
```

Please give any suggestion to load the svg image from the above mentioned URL link.

Comment: Is this drive link public? Also, have you tried an SVG from some other public source? A drive link could be an issue from your side

Comment: @FreakyAli, the drive is public and anyone can download/view the image. I have tried this [link](https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg) with filename and extension, it's working. But google drive link is not working.

Comment: Then there is probably something wrong with your drive link. Or drive is not supported

Comment: that link returns an HTML page containing an image, not a direct link to the image itself